# values unable to assign to struct

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I am unable to assign values to struct, d.
It is always 0.
I can't find the bug.

My print statement always prints x is: 0, y is 0

```
disc dArr[30];
struct disc *d ;

for (int i = 0; i < numDiscs; i++)
{
    d = &(dArr[numDiscs]);
    x_offset = d->pos[0];
    y_offset = d->pos[1];
    printf("The x is: %f\n", x_offset);
    printf("The y is: %f\n", y_offset);
}

typedef struct disc{
double pos[2];
} disc;
```

Comment: Is there a declaration for that?

Comment: Where is disc defined?

Comment: Did you allocate memory for it?

Comment: You need to make `d` point to a struct before attempting to assign to that struct.

Comment: Get rid of every `*`, and replace every `->` with a `.`.

Comment: Now that you've changed your code, what you probably want is `d = &(dArr[i])` instead of `d = &(dArr[numDiscs])`.

Comment: What is `numDiscs` BTW?

Comment: @goodvibration thanks! that is the bug i can't find

Comment: Getting the address of the element *past the end of the array* sounds like an off-by-one bug.

Comment: You may want to define it as `double x, y` to make the fields more meaningful. You can also print without intermediate variables, like `printf("At %.2f,%.2f (x,y)\n", d->pos[0], d->pos[1])`. You can also just `d = &dArr[i]` with no need for the braces.

Comment: it's a really stupid bug. Also partly because i wasn't confident with my pointers, that is why i missed the simplest thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
disc dArr[30];
struct disc *d ;

for (int i = 0; i < numDiscs; i++)
{
    d = &(dArr[numDiscs]);
    ...
}
```

Assuming that `numDiscs == sizeof(dArr) / sizeof(*dArr)`, attempting to access the object at address `&(dArr[numDiscs])` yields undefined behavior.

What you probably want is `&(dArr[i])`.